# How to prevent user credentials showing on URL after logging in in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, post, next.js, jwt

I want the user to log in and direct it to the homepage, instead the credentials of the user are showing in the URL  like so:
**http://localhost:3000/auth/login?email=test%40gmail.com&password=test**.

The token is being created correctly, but the redirecting is not working correctly. This is the handleSubmit function:

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
 async function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(state);
    const res = await fetch(LOGIN_API_BASE_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(state),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        credentials: "omit",
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      const json = await res.json();
      localStorage.setItem("token", json.token);
      router.push("/"); 
    } else {
      alert("Bad credentials");
    }
  }
```

I am using Java JWT to create the token and handling it with NextJS in the front end part.

I tried every solution possible and nothing did not work yet, I am guessing the back-end code is written correctly since the token is being created.
The state values if shown in the console are written like so:

**{email:"test@gmail.com", password: "test"}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour of your application. You need to manually prevent it. Pass the `event` from the button in the `handleSubmit()` function and call `preventDefault()` method.

So, in your button you'll do this,

```js
<button onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
</button>
```

And modify your code to call `preventDefault()`

```js
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    evnet.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    // rest of your code
  }
```